# Why can't Google Analytics record how long a user spends on your site?

Tags: google-analytics

Google Analytics can't tell how long bounce users (users who don't navigate past the landing page) spend on the site. But wouldn't it be possible, at least on desktop, to just record the initial time of the loading of the page, and then use javascript to record each mouse movement, each one replacing the one before, finally getting the time of the last movement, from which you'd subtract the initial load time?

Why can't Google Analytics do something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Please go to Audience - > User Explorer